# Is it safe to typecast a "type-erased" object?

Tags: java, oop, generics, type-erasure

A class (implementing a generic interface) has a method which returns `java.lang.Object` datatype instead of the expected. Is it safe to typecast it at the caller statement?

```java
import java.io.*; 
import java.lang.*;

interface dataCharge<A>{
    public A change(A ele); 
}

class APCDcharge implements dataCharge<APCDcharge>{
    private String name;
    private Integer charge;
    public void setName(String name){
        this.name = name;
    }
    public void setCharge(Integer charge){
        this.charge = charge;
    }
    public String getName(){
        return name;
    }
    public Integer getCharge(){
        return charge;
    }
    public String getKey(){
        return name+":"+charge;
    }
    @Override
    public APCDcharge change(APCDcharge ele){
        APCDcharge newele = new APCDcharge();
        newele.setCharge(ele.getCharge()+100);
        newele.setName(ele.getName());
        return newele;
    }
}

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        APCDcharge c = new APCDcharge();
        c.setName("ABC");
        c.setCharge(100);
        APCDcharge d = timePass(c);
        System.out.println(d.getKey());
    }
    private static <T extends dataCharge> T timePass(T element){
        T res = element.change(element);
        return res;
    }
}
```

The above code snippet gives error :

`error: incompatible types: Object cannot be converted to T
        T res = element.change(element);`

I also tried typecasting `element.change(element)` with `T` datatype like :

`T res = (T)element.change(element);`

And the code is compiling (with a warning: `Note: Main.java uses unchecked or unsafe operations.`), but executing correctly. Is that safe a way to remove the error? Is there any other way to correct it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is that in your `static` method the type bound of `T` is a raw type (`dataCharge`).

Make the following change:

```
private static <T extends dataCharge<T>> T timePass(T element){
    T res = element.change(element);
    return res;
}
```

i.e. `T extends dataCharge<T>` instead of `T extends dataCharge`.

Now the code will pass compilation without the cast.

Comment: Thank you sir, this works. I understand the mistake now.

Comment: This will only work if the type of `dataCharge` is a subtype of `dataCharge`, and thus is not an actual solution to the problem, except that it now compiles.

Comment: Sir @Bohemian what solution would you suggest me to implement? Like APCDcharge, I also have PCDcharge and BPCDcharge, and all these charges will be using the generic method timePass. So I planned to create an interface named `dataCharge` which is implemented by all three of them.

Answer (score 0):

This method:

```
static <T extends dataCharge> T timePass(T element){
    T res = element.change(element);
    return res;
}
```

Uses a *raw* (ie untyped) `dataCharge`. You should type it, plus return the type of `dataCharge`, not the (sub)class of `dataCharge`.

Given way you have used it, which is to pass itself into its own method, suggests that `dataCharge` should be more simply defined with as a *supplier* of `dataCharge` and directly access its own state when creating the result:

```
interface dataCharge<A>{
    public A change(); 
}

class APCDcharge implements dataCharge<APCDcharge> {
    // other code

    @Override
    public APCDcharge change() {
    APCDcharge newele = new APCDcharge();
    newele.setCharge(getCharge()+100);
    newele.setName(getName());
    return newele;
    }
}
```

Then your `timePass` method then becomes:

```
static <T> T timePass(dataCharge<T> element){
    T res = element.change();
    return res;
}
```

Comment: Are you sure your suggestions compile? Since element is passed to itself, I don't think that a separate `E` type variable would work.

Comment: @andy I’m pretty sure the `timePass` method compiles, although I only thumbed it in on my phone. Where it’s called won’t compile, but that’s not where the problem is. And the object doesn’t pass itself - that is a choice in this instance, but the type `dataCharge` is actually identical to a [`UnaryOperator`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/function/UnaryOperator.html), which is what `APCDcharge` should be declared as, ie `APCDcharge implements UnaryOperator<APCDcharge>`. I’ll amend my answer to be clear about what the problem is and how my answer applies.

Comment: @andy thank you for the link. The penny dropped. I have reworked and simplified my answer, which btw [compiles](http://ideone.com/DeLLN2).